# Mystifying "undefined constant" issue with Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mime, rest-client

I've got a Rails project where a constant is being nuked at some point while serving a request.

I'm using the `mime/types` and `restclient` gems. The `restclient` module defines an extension to `MIME` which contains the method `type_for_extension`.

```
module RestClient
    ...
    def stringify_headers headers
      result[key] = target_values.map { |ext| MIME::Types.type_for_extension(ext.to_s.strip) }.join(', ')
      ...
    end
  end
end

module MIME
  class Types
    def type_for_extension ext
      candidates = @extension_index[ext]
      candidates.empty? ? ext : candidates[0].content_type
    end
    class << self
      def type_for_extension ext
        @__types__.type_for_extension ext
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I can access `MIME::Types.type_for_extension` on my *first invocation* of a given controller action. On the second invocation, it's gone.

I can still use `MIME::Types.type_for`, but the added method is simply gone, so when I try to use the RestClient module it throws an exception on the line showin in `stringify_headers`:

```
NoMethodError, message: undefined method `type_for_extension' for MIME::Types:Class
```

**How is this possible? `type_for_extension` defined in the *same file* as `stringify_headers`; how could the latter get nuked but not the former?

---

**EDIT: FIXED IT!**

In my config:

```
config.gem "aws-s3", :version => ">= 0.6.2", :lib => "aws/s3"  
config.gem 'mime-types', :lib => 'mime/types'
```

`aws-s3` was loading `mime-types` via `require_library_or_gem`, which ultimate invoked `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_module!` which maintains a table called `autoloaded_constants` which are *nuked* when `ActionController.close` calls `Dispatcher.cleanup_application`.

Fix was to load `mime-types` first, so it's not autoloaded.

*whew*

Comment: I'd say your edit qualifies as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own question and I doubt anyone would object to an answer to something tricky like that.

Comment: @Mud Glad you were able to work out the issue.

Comment: Agree with mu. Please add your solution as an answer to your question, and mark it best answer. Answering your own questions is definitely allowed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answering my own question by request.*

In my config:

```
config.gem "aws-s3", :version => ">= 0.6.2", :lib => "aws/s3"  
config.gem 'mime-types', :lib => 'mime/types'
```

`aws-s3` library was loading `mime-types` via `require_library_or_gem`, which ultimately invoked `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_module!` which maintains a table called `autoloaded_constants` which are nuked when `ActionController.close` calls `Dispatcher.cleanup_application.`

Fix was to load mime-types first, so it's not autoloaded.